# kue job progress always 0

Tags: node.js, progress, kue

I am using kue for long running operations. And I want to be able to track the operations progress.

```
var kue = require('kue'),
queue = kue.createQueue();

var daJob = queue.create('da', {
    title: 'data analysis'
    , batchSize: req.params.batchSize
}).save( function(err){
   if( !err ) console.log( daJob.id );
});

// listeners on the different events
daJob.on('complete', function(result){
  console.log('Job completed with data ', result);
  daJob.remove();
}).on('failed attempt', function(errorMessage, doneAttempts){
    console.log('Job failed');
}).on('failed', function(errorMessage){
    console.log('Job failed');
}).on('progress', function(progress, data){
    console.log('progress'+progress);
});


queue.process('da', function(daJob, done){

    var total = 0;

    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            Col1.count({}, function(err, c) {
                total += c;
                callback();
            });
        },
        function(callback){
            Col2.count({}, function(err, c) {
                total += c;
                callback();
            });
        },
        function(callback){
            Col3.count({}, function(err, c) {
                total += c;
                callback();
            });
        }], function done(err, results) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            var count = 0;
            async.parallel([
                function (callback) {
                    var cur1 = col1.find().lean().cursor({batchSize: req.params.batchSize});
                    cur1.on('data', function (mobileTN) {
                        count++;
                        functions.workMobileRecord(mobileTN);
                        console.log('mobile ' +count/total);
                        daJob.progress(count,total);
                    });
                    cur1.on('close', function () {
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function (callback) {
                    var cur2 = col2.find().lean().cursor({batchSize: req.params.batchSize});
                    cur2.on('data', function (fixedTN) {
                        count++;
                        console.log(count/total);
                        daJob.progress(count,total);
                    });
                    cur2.on('close', function () {
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function (callback){
                    var cur3 = col3.find().lean().cursor({batchSize:req.params.batchSize});
                    cur3.on('data', function(videoTN){
                        count++;
                        console.log(count/total);
                        daJob.progress(count,total);
                    });
                    cur3.on('close', function () {
                        callback();
                    });
                }], function done(err, results) {
                    if (err) console.error(err);
                    done(results);
                });
            });
        });
```

When I print the progress variable inside the .on('progress') it always prints out as 0.

According to the documentation:

[Job Progress](https://github.com/Automattic/kue#job-progress)

> Job progress is extremely useful for long-running jobs such as video
>   conversion. To update the job's progress simply invoke
>   job.progress(completed, total [, data]):
>
> job.progress(frames, totalFrames); data can be used to pass extra
>   information about the job. For example a message or an object with
>   some extra contextual data to the current status.

How is it possible to debug this? Is the documentation not up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be problems with the kue.

After setting up a value for the data (which should be optional) it started working.

I also notice that sometimes the job stop having its progress event updated. The solution I found for that was to rename the job that is doing the work.